# Grok pattern from line - custom date

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to use a grok pattern to get the fields from the following. any help with this especially with the custom date?

0E7 10JUN21 23:37:53.8  Track 1   EZ: 100        EX: 72      Speed: 36   mph

I need to get the fields;

"date"
"time"
"Track 1"
"EZ"
"EX"
"Speed"

I have tried to get the date pattern but with no luck

Comment: And what is the pattern that you have tried? Are your log lines always in this same format? If so you can use dissect to parse it. Please update your question with the pattern that you tried.

Comment: I have disected it with 0E7 %{WORD:date} %{TIME:time} which gives me the date as a string but when i try and mutate it to date it comes up with issues n fails. The issue is the uppercase month i.e JUN.  The filter %{DATE:date} does not work

Comment: Check my answer on how to parse this date, if you need help with the other fields, please update your question with the expected field names and values for each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a custom grok to get the date, month and year in separated fields, then you will need to capitalize the month field and after that add a new field with the complete date string to use in the date filter.

To parse your date `10JUN21` into separated fields you can use the custom grok pattern.

```
(?<day>[0-9]{2})(?<month>[A-Z]{3})(?<year>[0-9]{2})
```

So, considering the message `0E7 10JUN21 23:37:53.8 Track 1 EZ: 100 EX: 72 Speed: 36 mph` and extracting the `date` and the `time` from it and making the transformations to parse the data, you will need the following configuration.

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => {
            "message" => "0E7 (?<day>[0-9]{2})(?<month>[A-Z]{3})(?<year>[0-9]{2}) %{TIME:time} %{GREEDYDATA}"
        }
    }
    mutate {
        capitalize => ["month"]
        add_field => { "datestring" => "%{month} %{day} %{year} %{time}"}
    } 
    date {
        match => ["datestring", "MMM dd yy HH:mm:ss.S"]
        remove_field => ["day","month","year","time"]
    }
}
```

This will give you the following result:

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2021-06-11T02:37:53.800Z,
       "message" => "0E7 10JUN21 23:37:53.8 Track 1 EZ: 100 EX: 72 Speed: 36 mph",
    "datestring" => "Jun 10 21 23:37:53.8"
}
```

As you can see the `@timestamp` field has the value of your date string, but relative to `UTC` as the `@timestamp` field uses UTC.

Comment: Perfect!. Thanks a lot